# How to get file extension from UploadedFile object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to get the extension of the file uploaded in rails?
is there any way other than using regex or sub-string?

something like :

```
params[:file].extension
```

Comment: This might help https://stuff-things.net/2016/06/29/get-the-mime-type-of-a-random-upload-in-rails/

Comment: @DeepakMahakale good one, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
File.extname(params[:file].original_filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that in `Content-Type` which comes along with the file params.

example: For images it could be `Content-Type: image/jpeg||(any image extentions..)`.
where as for pdf's `Content-Type: application/pdf`.